# Multiple Instance of ZeroClipboard clip not workinig

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I don't know what I am doing wrong in the code below, When I click on the Copy Code that I injected dynamically, I get only the last values viz (Text 264). on all the buttons. Can you please point out where I am wrong. Appreciate any kind of help.

```html
<div id="keylist">
       <p>Copy the code and insert into your homepage to display</p>

        <div class"row">

                     
            <pre> Text 1 </pre>
        </div>
        <div class"row">

                     
            <pre> Text 2 </pre>
        </div>
        <div class"row">

                     
            <pre> Text 4 </pre>
        </div>
        <div class"row">

                    
            <pre> Text 9 </pre>
        </div>
        <div class"row">

                      
            <pre> Text 264 </pre>
        </div>

   
</div>


<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        ZeroClipboard.setDefaults({ moviePath: '/Content/ZeroClipboard.swf' });
        var preNum = 1

        $('pre').each(function () {
            // Get a unique id for the element I will be inserting
            var id = 'copy-btn-' + preNum++
            // Capture the text to be copied to the clipboard
            var text = $(this).text()
           
            // Insert the element, just before this
            $('<div class="copy-btn" id="' + id + '-cont"><a class="icon-file icon-white" id="' + id + '">Copy Code</a></div>').insertBefore(this)
            // Capture the newly inserted element
            var elem = $(this).prev()
          
            // Create the clip, and glue it to the element
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard();


             clip.setText(text);

            clip.glue(elem[0]);
           
        })


    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of ZeroClipboard are you using?

Comment: I am using  v1.3.0-beta.1 of ZeroClipBoard

Comment: Fabricio, i have upgraded to  * v2.2.0  still its not working

Comment: Oh I just noticed that your question was missing the `javascript` and `jquery` tags, that explains why you hadn't got an answer earlier. `=]` Anyway, I've posted an answer for ZeroClipboard 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

ZeroClipboard 2.x changed the [API](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#api) quite a bit.

Using ZeroClipboard 2.2.0 (make sure to update ZeroClipboard's `.js` and `.swf` files):

```
ZeroClipboard.config({ swfPath: '/Content/ZeroClipboard.swf' });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('pre').each(function () {
        // Get the text to be copied to the clipboard
        var text = $(this).text();

        // Create the copy button
        var $copyBtn = $('<div class="copy-btn"><a class="icon-file icon-white">Copy Code</a></div>')
            .attr('data-clipboard-text', text) // set the text to be copied
            .insertBefore(this); // insert copy button before <pre>

        // Create the clip, and glue it to the copy button
        new ZeroClipboard($copyBtn);
    });
});
```

I've also cleaned up the code a bit, the IDs seemed unnecessary.